# creating a bootable Hackintosh USB flash drive to install Mac OSX to a HP Mini 110

Tags: macos

I don't have access to an external DVD drive, I do have a 16gb USB flash and a Windows 7 machine that I need for other things.

is it possible to install Mac OS X (iDeneb 1.3) to a HP mini 110 from Windows 7?

Comment: Legally? Because doing this will technically break the law.

Comment: didn't really want to get into a 'hacking is illegal' debate here. not even being able to talk about how to hack something is a pretty sad state of affairs if you ask me.

Comment: If the USB drive is an Apple product it qualifies as valid hardware. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing "illegal" about it... If you have a purchased copy of OSX you can install it on whatever you want without breaking the "law", just dont expect any Apple support.

Here is a link to do this, I've done the same already on my Toshiba Qosmio and am running OSX Lion perfectly. There are also tutorials to get OSX 10.6 Snow Leopeard installed as well if thats the version you have.

http://tonymacx86.blogspot.com/2011/10/unibeast-install-mac-os-x-lion-using.html

Comment: You've purchased the copy to install it on Apple hardware, not wherever you want.

Comment: thanks but it looks as if this depends on having a computer already running OSX

Comment: Its not "illegal", for your own personal uses and experimentation you can do with the legally purchased software as you please. 

http://wiki.osx86project.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

Comment: Correct thats the update from Snow Leopard to Lion. All you need is a retail copy of Snow Leopard DVD. There are tutorials on that site to use iBoot, your retail DVD disc, and multi-Beast to get OSX installed on an Intel based machine. Take a look around.

Comment: http://tonymacx86.blogspot.com/2010/04/iboot-multibeast-install-mac-os-x-on.html

Comment: For people ending up here: accepted or not, this answer is WRONG.  From the [Apple EULA](http://www.apple.com/legal/sla/docs/OSX1082.pdf) (from Mountain Lion 10.8.3 in this case): "you are granted a limited, nonexclusive license to install, use and run one (1) copy of the Apple Software on a single *Apple-branded computer* at any one time."